# How to set up a connection in Pentaho Kettle for Oracle using a SERVICE NAME instead of SID?

Tags: oracle, pentaho

[image]

This error shows up when I try to connect to database string host:port/servicename.

Answer (score 1):

To connect using a service name, you need to use the format `//host:port/servicename`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494317/391445

Comment: Ok, I guess the // at the beginning might make a difference. I was trying host:port/servicename. Actually, I found my answer while experimenting. In database name, simply put /servicename instead of the entire host:port/servicename string

Comment: Right: but I presume then the `servicename` is being looked up somehow, eg in `tnsnames.ora`? This may or may not be a good thing: good if you are using the same name resolution for other tools; bad if you now have to configure connections in two places.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just had to deal with this error.

The solution is when you configure the connection in Kettle, go into Options and add a line (substitute with your data):

```
database         <HOST_NAME>:<PORT>/<SERVICE_NAME>
```

This will override the URL that Kettle is generating